# C++: reading from a file with null characters

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have to read data from a file for an assignment unfortunately instead of spaces separating the various fields there are null characters. When taking integers from the file they are extracted fine however with the strings i just get a blanks space and garbage from my uninitialized character array. Any ideas as how to just extract the characters into my character array ignoring the null characters.

EDIT:

```
char fName[15],lName[15],pMethod[5],roomType[10],purpose[15];

int days, roomNum;

long guestID;

datafile>>guestID;
datafile.getline(fName,15,'\0');
datafile.getline(lName,15,'\0');

cout<<guestID<<endl;
cout<<fName<<endl;
cout<<lName<<endl;
```

is the code I'm using now unfortunately fName isnt grabbing anything other than null again
and lName is getting fName's string value. Was thinking about just getting the numbers as string and converting them.

Comment: Show your code that reads the strings, please.

Comment: char fName[15],lName[15],pMethod[5],roomType[10],purpose[15];
int days, roomNum;
long guestID;
  
datafile>>guestID>>fName>>lName>>pMethod>>days>>roomType>>roomNum>>purpose;

was what i was doing before i shall it using getline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) and pass `\0` (null character) as the delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

`std::getline` has an optional argument which is the delimiter character (`'\n'`, by default).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/ read the file to buffer in one go and then proceed from there.

Comment: You will have to watch out for correct memory allocation, and also, you'll have to parse the binary data yourself, including integer conversion. But in general, reading data in large chunks is often better. The link does the memory allocation right.

Answer (score -1):

Loop throught the bytes and ignore the null character bytes,