# Qt - Reading file containing multiple NULL characters

Tags: c++, qt, file, visual-studio-2017

I have gotten a file, which contains multiple NULL charactes `/0` in a line. My goal was to load the file and replace the `/0` with something else, but I experience some problems doing that.

Qt stops reading the file, after it get's to the point, where the NULL character appears.

Code:

```
QTextStream fileContent;
QFile file(pendingFile);
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    fileContent.append(file.readAll());
}
```

File:

```
Text
Text
Text /x00/x00/x00/x00/x00/x00/x00

More Text
```

I am currently using Qt 5.9.1 and develop with VS2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: reading from a file with null characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071313/c-reading-from-a-file-with-null-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file with as QDataStream

```
QFile file("raw.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream fileStream(&file);

qint64 fileSize = file.size();

QByteArray data(fileSize, '\0');
fileStream.readRawData(data.data(), fileSize)
```

In the ByteArray you can replace all \0 elements.

Update (comments, look at **underscore_d**'s answer):

```
data.replace('\0','_');
QString dataString(data);
```

Comment: how do you definde filesize? file.size() ?

Comment: I've tried your code and added `QString dataString = data;` to show me, if it works, but it still stops at the null charcter

Comment: QString stops after a \0, called a null terminated string. You cannot see anything after a \0! Look in the ByteArray with the debugger and you can see all \0. Replace the \0 in the ByteArray and convert after that to QString.

Comment: @betaros Yes. Code expecting text does that, basically everywhere. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that `QFile` stops reading at `NUL` (i.e. `'\0'`, not the `NULL` macro), but rather that `QTextStream` considers a `NUL` to mean end-of-string and thus stops `append()`ing after the first `NUL` it encounters.

[Here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27345-parsing-messages-with-NUL-(-0-)-terminated-tokens-into-QByteArray) is a previous thread on another site discussing something very similar, with a suggested alternative, which boils down to this:

You need to replace the `NUL`s before feeding them into the `QTextStream`, as it will not pass them through. The suggestion there is to use a `QDataStream`. Maybe you don't need a `TextStream` or any `Stream` at all, and could just read the files into memory as binary and replace the `NUL`s with your choice of substitute before writing out again.